# NGINX and uWSGI work but don't begin at startup

Tags: raspbian, web-server

I have followed this tutorial to install uwsgi with nginx: [Setting up Nginx and uWSGI for CGI scripting](http://raspberrywebserver.com/cgiscripting/setting-up-nginx-and-uwsgi-for-cgi-scripting.html).

It all works, but it only works after I execute the command

```
sudo -u www-data ./uwsgi ./uwsgi_config.ini
```

I have to mention that I run headless and do all the work from a ssh terminal.

After I execute the command I cannot do anything else, unless I stop `uwsgi` with Ctrl-C (it just shows when a script a running). 
How to keep it running in the background and start it on startup? I tried to add it to `.bashrc` but I still cannot use the console until I end `uwsgi`.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I think you're missing something in that listed command.

Comment: I am able to run it in the background by adding -d file.log but I still can t start it with nginx. I need to start it up manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `screen` with a cronjob. This is what I do when I need to run something in the background at boot.

To do this, you will need to install `screen` with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Once that's done, edit your `crontab` file with:

```
crontab -e
```

and add this line to the bottom:

```
@reboot screen -d -m -S uwsgi sudo -u www-data ./uwsgi ./uwsgi_config.ini
```

and then reboot. It should be running in the background once your boot has finished. To attach the screen and see the script running, enter the command:

`screen -r uwsgi`

If you want to exit that screen without killing it, hit CTRL+A+D. (All three keys at the same time.)

Comment: I did it using just crontab. Thank you, screen was not needed, I just added -d file.log, created a file.log with permission 754 and that s it.

Comment: @Cezar Happy to help!

Comment: Upvote because this will work, but the best way would be to just use `systemd`!

Answer (score 2):

The "right way" to do this is to create a `systemd` service.

Put the following in `/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service` (make sure to change `/path/to/project/directory`):

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance

[Service]
ExecStartPre=-/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown www-data:www-data /run/uwsgi;'
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'cd /path/to/project/directory; uwsgi --ini uwsgi_config.ini'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable uwsgi
```

Then restart the system; it will start on boot now!

While `screen` may work; it's a hack. The `init` system is how programs are started and stopped automatically under Linux, and `systemd` is the modern `init` system used by Raspbian.

Anything you put in `ExecStartPre` will be run before the program is started, and `ExecStart` is the command used to actually run the program.